# September 2012 Release ajax toolkit combobox is read only when using jquery

Tags: asp.net, ajax, toolkit

Asp.net September 2012 Release ajax toolkit combobox is read only when using jquery. Any idea on how to avoid conflicts between jquery and ajax toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have other libraries together with jQuery you can use the [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function to avoid the conflicts with the common symbols like the `$`

Sample from [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and how you use the `noConflict()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

The idea is that after you call the `$.noConflict();` then all rest call to jQuery libraries are done using the `jQuery` and not the `$` symbol as on the example above.